# Stop jmeter.log logging out third party logs

Tags: logging, jmeter, log4j, log4j2, jmeter-logging

I have a JSR223 sampler that uses Tiny Radius but when I run the script, jmeter.log fills up with info messages from org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient and packet information.

Is there something I can add to my jmeter.properties to stop this, or at least drop the logging level to error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***PRE v3.2***

in `bin/jmeter.properties`:

```
log_level.[package_name].[classname]=[PRIORITY_LEVEL]
```

with `classname` being optional

So:

```
log_level.org.tinyradius.util=ERROR
```

***3.2 onwards***

In `bin/log4j2.xml`:

```
<Logger name="org.tinyradius.util" level="error" />
```